# Product management for wordpress

Tags: wordpress, user-roles

Hi I wanted my wordpress site putting user role for product I want the user1 can only see and count the product he uploaded and he cannot see the other product uploaded by the other user is there a free plugin for that in wordpress ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try to use this

https://wordpress.org/plugins/user-role-editor/

this allow to add various capability to the user, may it will help?